# select table like MS Word in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, npm-install

In MS Word there is a feature to select and create a table like this:

[image]

In my case, I want result to be an array like: [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]] for a 3x2 table
I don't know the keywords to search for it, or is there a package that supports this?

Answer (score 1):

My answer(with bootstrap) [image]

```
const Demo = () => {
   const [nodeHover, setNodeHover] = useState([0, 0]);
   const [currentNode, setCurrentNode] = useState([0, 0]);
   ...
   return (
     <div>
         {Array(5)
            .fill(Array(5).fill(0)) // 5x5 0 array
            .map((e, i) => (
              <div className="row-node">
                {e.map((e2, i2) => (
                  <div
                    className={
                      "single-node border border-secondary text-danger " +
                       (currentNode[0] >= i && currentNode[1] >= i2
                       ? "border-danger border-4 " : " ") //border all selected nodes
                       + (nodeHover[0] >= i && nodeHover[1] >= i2
                        ? "bg-secondary ": " ") //background color all hovered nodes 
                    }
                    onMouseOver={() => setNodeHover([i, i2])}
                    onClick={() => setCurrentNode([i, i2])}
                  >
                    {" "}
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
            ))}
         <h3>selected {(currentNode[0] + 1) * (currentNode[1] + 1)} nodes</h3>
         <h3>Now coordinates {"(" + currentNode[0] + ";" + currentNode[1] + ")"}</h3>
     </div>)
}
```

style.css

```
.row-node {
  height: 32px;
}

.single-node {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 1px;
```